# Drupal 8 Webform - Change to Dev Version

Tags: 8, webforms

I need to send emails in Drupal 8 Webform conditionally based on what the user has selected. I know this feature was added in the most recent release in  8.x-5.x-dev, but I have the beta branch installed (8.x-5.0-beta16). Is there an easy way for me to change to this version of the module, or am I out of luck?

Thanks,
Lisa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have drush on your server you can easily select a version with this command

```
drush dl webform --select
```

it should show something like this

```
Choose one of the available releases for webform:
 [0]  :  Cancel                                                    
 [1]  :  8.x-5.x-dev     -  2017-Sep-07  -  Development            
 [2]  :  8.x-5.0-beta16  -  2017-Aug-08  -  Supported, Recommended 
 [3]  :  8.x-4.x-dev     -  2016-Nov-28  -  Development
```

and you could press 1 then enter to select 5.x-dev

i believe you'd also be prompted with a message warning you that you're overwriting the previously installed beta16 version and you'll say ok

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed your site using composer you can try this command

```
composer require drupal/webform:5.x-dev
```